# How to use progress bar in splash activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, progress-bar, splash-screen, android-progressbar

I want a progress bar in splash activity but doesn't know how to do it.Anyone knows please do help me. Thanks!

Comment: post your code of splash screen

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
  Thread thread=new Thread(){
   @Override
   public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
     sleep(2000);
     Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     
    } catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO: handle exception
    }
   }
  };
  thread.start();
 }

Comment: @PareshMayani i dont know how to code a progress bar ...just done a splash screen yet